# Attach event handler to Session_End event ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, events, session

One of the projects that I am working currently requires auto save page. The page under question is very long and user is mandated to write comments in "Notes" input box, these notes are huge and we donot want to loose them when session times out or user is idle for a  long duration.

FYI .. This a ASP.Net MVC application

Comment: what about to use localstorage? and time to time save user input before actual submit, just in case?

Comment: I am thinking of firing jquery unload event ... I haven't tried this yet but hopeful that this will solve my requirements at hand.